# Is there a more efficient route towards brute-forcing a random distirbution whilst implementing constraints?

Tags: python, numpy, while-loop

I have a function that generates a set of mixtures that satisfy specified constraints. my code:

```
def generate_mix():
    while True:
        n2 = np.random.uniform(0.0,1.15)
        c2 = np.random.uniform(0.1,10.3)
        c3 = np.random.uniform(0.02,2.66)
        ic4 = np.random.uniform(0,0.71)
        nc4 = np.random.uniform(0,0.71)
        ic5 = np.random.uniform(0,0.04)
        nc5 = np.random.uniform(0,0.01)

        if (n2/c2 <= 0.3 and
            0.20 >= c3/c2 <= 0.26 and
            0.20 >= ic4/c3 <= 0.27 and
            nc4/ic4 <= 1 and
            ic5/nc4 <= 0.06 and
            nc5/ic5 <= 0.25):

            comp_list = [c2, c3, ic4, nc4, ic5, nc5, n2]
            comp_list.insert(0, 100 - sum(comp_list))
            return comp_list
            break

big_list = [generate_mix() for _ in range(1000)]
```

The code takes roughly 18 seconds to run on my computer. I was wondering is there was a more efficient way for this kind of while loop? .. it's kind of brute forcing the uniform distribution which maybe why it's taking so long.

If not then I guess I'll just live with it.

The emphasis is on generating mixtures that are within the ranges specified in the numpy random distribution. This is a must for my application.

Comment: what does the profiler tell you?

Comment: Do you have some of the inequalities in your if statement flipped around?  The way that a couple of them are written is redundant. Ex: `0.20 >= c3/c2 <= 0.26` is equivalent to just `c3/c2 <= 0.20`.  Did you mean `0.20 <= c3/c2 <= 0.26`? Regardless, this shouldn't be causing any noticeable performance hits, but it makes the code less readable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is generate your independent variables first, then generate your dependant ones, rather than generate them all and do it again if it doesn't satisfy your constraints.

So I would do

```
def generate_mix():
  c2 = np.random.uniform(0.1, 10.3)
```

then since n2/c2 must be <= 0.3

```
  n2 = np.random.uniform(0.0, max(1.15, .3/c2))
```

and so on.

Comment: this will not produce a uniform distribution over the parameter space

Comment: @pseudoDust but you're not selecting from the uniform distribution, you're generating and filtering first. This has the same result without all the busy-work.

Comment: If it was a normal distribution instead of uniform then it would not be the same to filter first, but with a uniform it should be the same (unless I forget my stats classes which were quite some time ago!)

Comment: This will not yield the same results, lets take a simple example: `a=rand(0,1)` `b=rand(0,1)` `b/a<1`, you would do `b=rand(0,a)`, now `P(a<0.1)=0.1` but clearly `P(b<0.1)>0.1` while in the first method they had equal distribution...

Comment: I will check this and the distributions when i get home

Comment: an additional complication is many random number generator implementations are NOT pairwise independent. However I think pseudoDust is correct that my implementation has a bias. If you select pairs of random numbers, you can see that high n2's would be less likely than low ones, but also low c2's would be less likely than high ones. So unless you can sort out the math for what the new distribution is, I think you are stuck doing it the inefficient way (unless you don't care about preserving the multivariate random distribution)

Comment: This solution worked but I had to make some tweaks to ensure the proper ratios were met because the ic4.nc4,ic5,nc5s were not correct. Thanks for your input. Also, i did the ratios specifically comparing each component to c2.

Comment: It drastically improved the efficiency btw!

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate_mix():
    while True:
        c2 = np.random.uniform(0.1, 10.3)
        n2 = np.random.uniform(0.0, max(1.15, .111/c2))
        c3 = np.random.uniform(min(0.02,0.2), max(2.66, 0.26/c2))
        ic4 = np.random.uniform(0, max(0.71, 0.07/c2))
        nc4 = np.random.uniform(0, max(0.71, 0.07/c2))
        ic5 = np.random.uniform(0, 0.04)
        nc5 = np.random.uniform(0, 0.01)

        if nc4/ic4 <=1 and ic5/nc4 <= 0.06 and nc5/ic5 <= 0.25:
            comp_list = [c2,c3,ic4,nc4, ic5, nc5,n2]
            comp_list.insert(0, 100 - sum(comp_list))

            return comp_list
            break
```